# Visual Studio Find and Replace 2 Strings Using Regex

Tags: regex, string, visual-studio-2012, replace, find

I wonder is it possible to find a value from a string and use it in another string?

For example:

```
<string id="1" name="foo" /> // I want to get "foo"(without quotes) from this 

<string id="1" name="exp" /> // I want to change exp to foo
```

I cant just simply copy everthing else other than name value because there is so many different variables other then id with different values.

Is it possible to the in visual studio? Or is possible to do it in another platform? I can write a code to do it but if there is an already solution for it I'd like to know.

Thank you..

Comment: Are these strings in the same file?

Comment: Yes. It is an xml file

Comment: I'd probably use ruby + [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to parse the XML, find each instance of an `id` attribute, and store it and the `name` in a map if it doesn't already exist, otherwise replace the `name` attribute with the `name` stored in the map. A regex on its own is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex to match the name value:

```
(?<=<string\b[^<]*\bname="([^"]+)"[\s\S\r]*?<string\b[^<]*\bname=")[^"]+
```

And replace with `$1`.

[image]

For some reason, to match text across multiple lines, we need to add `\r` to the `[\s\S]` character class.